# How to make NetworkManager work without ConsoleKit

Tags: networking, gnome, arch-linux

I reinstalled Arch half a month ago. I found that the Consolekit is no longer available in newer versions.
Previously I use consolekit to configure my Networkmanger, but I didn't know how to solve that...

I tried to install Networkmanager and use `sudo systemctl start NetworkManager` to start it after running `... enable...`.
And GNOME notifies `activation of network failed`. I think that's because there is no consolekit.
So add new wireless account is not available for me.
For `gdm`, I just use `sudo systemctl enable gdm` to make it autostart, without a `~/.xinitrc` file.
I posted that problem in the mail-list for Chinese users . https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgr … IDl8F8NbqU
Then I use netcfg instead. But I really want to make networkmanager work in GNOME 3.6 .  Please help me.

More details:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=153388